# Apple MapKit 3D flyover

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is there any public iOS 8 API available to implement 3D flyover or at least 3D view as shown on Apple Maps App screenshot below?

[image]

**Update**

After below suggestions I've done following code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        mapView.showsBuildings = true
        let eiffelTowerCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.85815,2.29452)
        mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(eiffelTowerCoordinates, 1000,100)

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard

        // 3D Camera
        let mapCamera = MKMapCamera()
        mapCamera.centerCoordinate = eiffelTowerCoordinates
        mapCamera.pitch = 45
        mapCamera.altitude = 500
        mapCamera.heading = 45

        // Set MKmapView camera property
        self.mapView.camera = mapCamera
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Now my App looks similar to Apple Maps App but unfortunately not identical.

[image]

**Is anybody knows how to add all textures to buildings?**

**Update 2**

Google Maps iOS SDK checked. 
Absolutely same story. 
No 3D buildings in any mode except `kGMSTypeNormal`
That means no textured buildings available.

Following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(48.85815, longitude: 2.29452, zoom: 50, bearing:30, viewingAngle:40)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
        mapView.buildingsEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Renders following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this article can help you get the background info you need: http://nshipster.com/mkgeodesicpolyline/

Comment: @GuyKogusthank you! The article is excellent. But it is not about 3D maps.

Comment: I thought it might help with the flyover logic. Oh well, good luck :)

Comment: As François Lagunas said, replace `mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard` by `mapView.mapType = .HybridFlyover` and boom !

Answer (score 13):

You can now use the new iOS 9 MKMapTypeSatelliteFlyover type.

[image: Test App Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Found this in the MapKit Reference:

[Reference Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsBuildings)

> showsBuildings A Boolean indicating whether the map displays extruded
>   building information.
>
> Declaration SWIFT var showsBuildings: Bool OBJECTIVE-C
>   @property(nonatomic) BOOL showsBuildings Discussion   When this
>   property is set to YES and the camera has a pitch angle greater than
>   zero, the map extrudes buildings so that they extend above the map
>   plane, creating a 3D effect. The mapType property must be set to
>   MKMapTypeStandard for extruded buildings to be displayed. The default
>   value of this property is YES.
>
> Import Statement import MapKit
>
> Availability Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

[MKMapCameraClass:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapCamera_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapCamera/pitch)

> pitch The viewing angle of the camera, measured in degrees.
>
> Declaration SWIFT var pitch: CGFloat OBJECTIVE-C @property(nonatomic)
>   CGFloat pitch Discussion A value of 0 results in a camera pointed
>   straight down at the map. Angles greater than 0 result in a camera
>   that is pitched toward the horizon by the specified number of degrees.
>   If the map type is MKMapTypeSatellite or MKMapTypeHybrid, the pitch
>   value is clamped to 0.
>
> The value in this property may be clamped to a maximum value to
>   maintain map readability. There is no fixed maximum value, though,
>   because the actual maximum value is dependent on the current altitude
>   of the camera.
>
> Import Statement import MapKit
>
> Availability Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please take a look to my question update above.

Comment: >If the map type is MKMapTypeSatellite or MKMapTypeHybrid, the pitch value is clamped to 0.

I believe you would have to get the textures yourself and use an MKOverlay of some description. The API does not allow for the textures found in the system "Maps" app.

Comment: So, basically it is impossible to replicate first screenshot using MapKit. Anyway thank you four your comments!

Comment: From what I can see yes. But it may be possible using the Google Maps For iOS SDK: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: any one is here. who can guide me to set camera tilt in MKMapTypeHybrid and MKMapTypeSatellite mode? want the feature same like MKMapTypeStandard view when setting pitch value is 50 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want, you have to play with the camera. You'll have to update the pitch, heading, and altitude if needed.

Have a look here, you'll find everything : [MKMapCamera Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapCamera_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapCamera)

**Update :**
Unfortunately, you can't pitch maps who are satellite or hybrid.

> If the map type is MKMapTypeSatellite or MKMapTypeHybrid, the pitch value is clamped to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please take a look to my question update above.

Answer (score 0):

**mapType** property of **MKMapView** enum can be used to change the map type or region.

[image: Screenshot 1]

You can use `hybridFlyover` property to show satellite image along with flyover data where it is available.

**Usage:**

```
objMapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
```

Here, objMapView is an instance of MKMapView class.

[image: Screenshot 2]