# How to enable MKMapView 3D view?

Tags: macos, mapkit

I have an MKMapView in a window, and `pitchEnabled` is true (and I've confirmed this in the debugger).  The "3D" thingy in the middle of the compass is grayed out, and clicking or dragging it does nothing.  Option-dragging the map (like I do in Maps.app) doesn't do anything, either.

From my interpretation of the docs, setting `pitchEnabled` should let me use the 3D view, like Maps.app does.  Am I mistaken?  Is there something else I need to do to allow my users to get a 3D map view?

Comment: Does your MKMapView object have a camera (property)?

Comment: @rocky: `camera` is a non-nullable property, so can't *not* have one.  (I've confirmed in the debugger that it has one.)  Do I need to set it to anything in particular to let the user control the pitch?

Comment: Well I was reading the documentation for pitchEnabled and it says, "When this property is set to YES and a valid camera is associated with the map...". So the question is what is a valid camera?

Comment: Have you tried this sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW11

Answer (score 11):

You can get close to the experience of 3D mode by adjusting the camera angle from which you view the map and making buildings visible. The example below allows you view the Eiffel Tower in 3D:

```
viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    mapView.showsBuildings = true // displays buildings

    let eiffelTowerCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.85815, 2.29452)
    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(eiffelTowerCoordinates, 1000, 100) // sets the visible region of the map

    // create a 3D Camera
    let mapCamera = MKMapCamera()
    mapCamera.centerCoordinate = eiffelTowerCoordinates
    mapCamera.pitch = 45
    mapCamera.altitude = 500 // example altitude
    mapCamera.heading = 45

    // set the camera property
    mapView.camera = mapCamera
}
```

example from: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144508/apple-mapkit-3d-flyover)

Comment: I done this and some how kept ending up in Africa. I suggest you just mess with just the current camera's pitch, altitude, and heading. Less lines of code that does the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Since OS X El Capitan v10.11 they added a new map type: "3D flyover mode"

For some reason this option doesn't show up in XCode attributes inspector of the mapview. You have to set it programmatically. This makes the map look and behave as the one seen in the maps app.

```
self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatelliteFlyover;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in swift on iOS 11:

```
mapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
```

That is giving me the 3D view.

Answer (score 0):

Use this setup method to configure you MapView in viewDidLoad.

```
func setup() {
        objMapView.showsUserLocation = true
        objMapView.delegate = self
        objMapView.showsBuildings = true
        objMapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover

        objLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        if let center = self.objLocationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let currentLocationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude, center.longitude)
            objMapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: currentLocationCoordinates, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 100)

            // create a 3D Camera
            let mapCamera = MKMapCamera()
            mapCamera.centerCoordinate = currentLocationCoordinates
            mapCamera.pitch = 45
            mapCamera.altitude = 100
            mapCamera.heading = 45

            // set the camera property
            objMapView.camera = mapCamera
        }
    }
```

In above code snippet:

`mapType` property `hybridFlyover` displays satellite map along with location names if available.

`MkMapCamera` instance helps in creating 3D view of map. `altitude` property determine altitude from where location is to be projected.

Check below screenshot for output:

[image: Screenshot 1]